# My 'app name' not accepted in Actions on Google simulator, only "test app"

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, jovo-framework

I'm setting up about my 10th (test/demo) Action on Google, and the simulator ONLY supports me starting my brand new app via "Talk to my test app".

How do I get to the point I can say "Talk to {my app name here}"?

IN THE PAST, after setting up all the Action details (via 'Overview' screen), and clicking 'TEST DRAFT', it usually resolves and the simulator starts suggesting to me "Talk to {my app name here}".

But this time it's not happening. It's stuck on "Talk to my test app", and has been for almost 24 hours.

**Does anyone know the magical incantation required to get the Actions Simulator to accept invocations using my actual app name?**

I'm using Dialogflow, which was all setup using the [Jovo framework](https://www.jovo.tech/) actually - using 'jovo deploy' to stand up the Dialogflow agent and Actions config. I can't see that Jovo would have anything to do with the issue here, but you never know with software! All the config in Dialogflow and Actions looks good to me.

Comment: Hey there! I ran into a similar problem when I recorded a demo video for Jovo. It starts around here: https://youtu.be/6ypo5X6tKHc?t=8m53s.
In the video, I change the invocation name and it even works when the console is telling you that the name is not allowed. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Hey @JanKönig, see my comment in the accepted answer below. It seems that Jovo creates multiple English 'locales' in Dialogflow (and hence they show up as 'Localized' locales in Actions). Haven't seen this DF feature before, and it confused me! And will surely confuse others. I reckon you need to cover this in the doco... Cheers.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Yes, this is a design decision we had to make, as standard Alexa Skills are e.g. 'en-US', while DF agents are 'en'. Definitely need to work on making this more intuitive. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've described sounds like it should work, but it sounds like you should double-check for any errors.

In the Actions Console, make sure you don't have any errors indicated on the overview screen. If you do (or even if you don't), click on the Edit button for stage 2: App Information.

[image]

In there, check the error messages to make sure they're not applying to the name or pronunciation. Make sure both the name and pronunciation are valid and accepted.

If you're working in more than one language, make sure these are set ok for all the languages you have set.

[image]

Test it from the `Simulator` link on the left navigation instead of going back through Dialogflow. They should do the same thing, but it sounds like it is possible that isn't taking in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Turned out to be the Languages issue. I used Jovo to create en-US and en-AU. In the Actions on Google Overview, all looked well with "English" selected. But 2-clicks under that, I now see that there are "English-All", "English-US (localized)" and "English-AU (localized)". Although all the "All" config was good, the "Localized" variants were not. Specifically - 'Name' and 'Details' sub-sections were blank. Is this normal behaviour? Or something strange with the Jovo creation process I wonder?

Comment: Further to first comment - The 'localized' EN entries seems to be due to Jovo making multiple 'locales' in Dialogflow (perfectly reasonable since Americans can't spell   ;-p   ), and flow-on effects from that.

Comment: anyway to do it in dialogflow?

Comment: @Sana - I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like it might merit being a new question. Go ahead and create a new StackOverflow question, providing as many details as you can.